# Detect FLASH plugin crashes

Tags: javascript, flash, browser, crash

Is there any way to detect flash-plugin crashes in major browsers (firefox, ie, chrome, safari and opera) via javascript?

Comment: Curious as what your trying to accomplish with detection.

Comment: He might want to refresh the page?

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure whether that works or not. You can periodically get a reference to flash object and check whether it has the method SetVariable.

```
function checkFlashCrashed() {
   try {
      var tmp = document.getElementById("flashObjectId").SetVariable;
      if(!tmp) {
         alert("Flash crashed");
         return;
      }
   } catch (e) {
      alert("Flash crashed");
      return;
   }
   setTimeout(checkFlashCrashed, 1000); // check it out every one second
}
```

SetVariable is an interface function that can be called from Javascript code. If flash crashes, its interface should crash, too. Hence, that may be a solution.

Comment: +1. It works like a charm with Chrome 23.0.12.71. Sadly, OP was a newbie/troll.

Comment: This seems as a valid and correct answer but OP still doesn't care :).

Comment: haven't tested it, flash is dead =D

Comment: You asked this on 2010. You could have tested it and accepted this as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use global exception handling in ActionScript to call an external interface on UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR.

When an error occurs in the Flash Player runtime, it may catch the exception and signal JavaScript.

Comment: yeah, but what about in case when you dont have an access to code of your player? For example: youtube player crashes on the page, how to detect?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a keep alive script in your as3 file that talks to the page js, if the js doesn't get a call for a few seconds, you could have it time out and handle it as a flash crash.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you feel about false positives.

You can have a watchdog that make a ajax call "The flash has not crashed", if the flash seems to still be working.  And asume that flash has crashed if is not written. This will create false positives if the user close the page before the check.

You can have a watchdog that make a ajax call "The flash has crashed", if the flash seems to not work. This will miss crashes, like crash that kill the whole browser with it.

Maybe you can have both watchdogs so you get a better idea of whats going on.