# How to detect YouTube iFrame failure due to Flash crashing?

Tags: flash, error-handling, google-chrome-extension, youtube-javascript-api

I've been working on a Google Chrome extension for a while now. I've noticed that Flash has been crashing quite commonly lately and I would like to have my extension gracefully recover from such an event.

[I found a post talking about testing a Flash element directly,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329022/detect-flash-plugin-crashes) but I am using YouTube's iFrame API. When I try to call SetVariable on the iFrame, not surprisingly, it always fails.

Any ideas on other ways I could detect my player having crashed so that I may respond accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced in that but I think you can register an event handler for the onError event the API provide, alternatively you can check periodically the time elapsed calling the getCurrentTime() method.

Comment: I've actually tried both of these implementations without success already.

When Flash crashes, the player doesn't generate an onError event. I suspect it dies before it can fire the event.

My next attempt, I created a setInterval which ran player.getPlayerState() against the iFrame every 5 seconds. After Flash crashed, the code continued to gracefully execute. I should've checked the return values, I can do that next, but I was surprised it didn't yield to an exception. I'll try and post some code to backup my findings tonight.