# How do you auto refresh a webpage when Flash crashes?

Tags: javascript, flash

I'm wondering if there is a way to make a script that could possibly detect when Flash crashes, then refresh the page or maybe delete that tab then create an identical one.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect FLASH plugin crashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329022/detect-flash-plugin-crashes)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to call Flash functions from Javascript.
It's possible to call Javascript functions from Flash.

You could certainly set up something that calls flash (or vice versa) and expects feedback every so often.  Flash really shouldn't crash tho.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html